# How to fix cors error at my keycloak to make it work?

Tags: cors, keycloak

I try to reach this keycloak endpoint: http://10.10.10.10:8999/auth/realms/demo-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token

I add the client_secret, grant_type and client_id. Then when I send the request from my frontend app, I get back this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://10.10.10.10:8999/auth/realms/demo-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

My keycloak setup is the following:

-confidential client

-valid redirect URIs: *

-web origins: + or * (tried both)

Also tried to set valid uris to `http://localhost:4200` and web origins `+` or add the `http://localhost:4200` to web origins.

It's important that the client have to be confidential or the access_token won't contain a resource-id when I try to use it...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here, a post using similar setup: https://symbiotics.co.za/integrating-keycloak-with-an-angular-4-web-application-part-2/

Comment: I find some posts about some problems with angular and confidential client, having problems like you. Somes argues that it do not accept `http` calls, others about `*` conflict. Can you serve your keycloak on `https`?

Comment: No I can't. Only http. For example from Postman I can reach the endpoint and get back the access_token.

Comment: Requests with Postman are made with `redirect_uri` parameter?

Comment: Did you check if the client you use includes the Origin header in the token request? Browsers usually do it, however other clients such as Postman don't do it by default. If you don't send an Origin header, no Access-Control-Allow-Origin will be set.

Comment: @stackstack293 Did you fix your problem?

Answer (score 2):

On keycloak client setup, add `http://localhost:4200/*` as valid redirect URI. In web origins a `+` is the best choice.

If you are using Java adapter, also set `enable-cors` tor `true` (see https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_java_adapter_config)

Comment: To be honest I have no idea whre to set that enable-cors to true but I try to use from angular

Comment: It's on Java adapter only

Comment: By the way I tried this aswell. Exactly this. `http://localhost:4200/*` and `+`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
webOrgins : localhost:4200
```